# Why does the Rutherford engine seem to ignite instantly?

Tags: rocketlab, electron, rutherford-engine

A highlight of any Rocket Lab Electron launch is second stage ignition, seen from an impressive angle in this video from Flight 16:

Notably ignition seems instantaneous almost like an SRB or pressure fed engine, despite Rutherford being a liquid pump-fed engine. Why is this? Does it have to do with the fuel pumps being electrically driven?

Comment: Do you have any other video of a second stage to compare? It has to be igniting in vacuum, filmed from below, with an exposure adjusted for parts in the shadow.

Comment: Agree with @asdfex -- this could well be a  matter of exposure control leading to an apparently much "brighter" ignition than reality.

Comment: I don't really know, but I'd suggest that they're pretty small engines (9.8 inch diameter), maybe the small size helps to make it quick. Plus the battery-powered turbopump, which would be running on full power pretty much immediately.

Comment: @asdfex Here is a video showing ignition from 2nd stage perspective: https://youtu.be/VRfm6RGVHf8?t=1003 I'll admit, exposure probably has something to do with it, but still ignition seems quick compared to other engines.

Comment: My guess would be the size of the engine combined with the electric pumps as well. Remember that a turbo pump is essentially also a rocket engine, so you first have to start the small rocket engine to start the big rocket engine. And in order to start the small rocket engine, you typically have to start it spinning first using some sort of compressed gas or pressure-fed liquid. So, you first pressure-feed some propellant into  the starter, which starts the turbo pump spinning, then you can ignite the turbo pump engine, once that is running, you can start pumping fuel into the large engine, and

Comment: lastly ignite that.

Comment: Such a cool video; I'm so glad their space microphone was turned on!